# Get milliseconds from date Flex

Tags: apache-flex, date-format, milliseconds

Hi i have a csharp application and a flex application and in both i get the currentdatetime and format it. The millisecoonds i get in my flex application seem to be legging behind in comparison the the milliseconds i get when using the csharp application. I am not sure if i am  doing something wrong but this is my flex function that formats my date. Please let me know if this is the right way to get the following date format yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.fff  in flex.

```
    private function GetCurrentDateTime():void
{
            var dateFormatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
            dateFormatter.formatString = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS'; 

            var dtCurrent:Date = new Date();                
            currDateTime = String(dateFormatter.format(dtCurrent) + '.' + dtCurrent.getMilliseconds());                             
}
```

Comment: The more recent Spark alternative is [DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html), and I believe it must be lowercase y and d. But you can find that information in the docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "legging Behind"?  Do you mean that C# and Flex are giving two different values?  Unless you call the two functions to retrieve the current date/time at exactly the same time [on the same machine], isn't this to be expected?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on the DateFormatter class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#formatString

I believe the formatstring you need would be `YYYY/MM/DD HH:NN:SS.QQQ`

Note: HH returns hours from 1-24.  JJ can be used to return hours from 0-23